# Double square brackets in TikZ with pgfmathparse?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Why can’t I use `\llbracket` in the following example?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,graphs,graphs.standard,quotes}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\def\a{{
"\llparenthesis"
,"\llbracket" % With this line, it fails!
,"\llparenthesis"
}}

\draw (0,1) node{$\llparenthesis$};
\draw (1,1) node{$\llbracket$};

\foreach \x in {0,1}
{\draw (\x, 0) node {$\pgfmathparse{\a[\x]}\pgfmathresult$};} % (*)

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

1. Using `\llparenthesis` and `\llbracket` in normal draw works
2. Using `\llparenthesis` works when using it in `\pgfmathparse`, indexing from array, whereas `llbracket` in the same place doesn’t (line (*))
3. Both commands are from the `stmaryrd` package (not including the package doesn’t doesn’t allow 1.).

Activating the commented line produces this error:

> ! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `4' or`44' (in '{
>   "\llparenthesis " ,"\delimiter "444A471 " ,"\llparenthesis " }[0]').
>   See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because one of them is a character `\mathcar"444C` hence `"<char>"` works off the bat. The other one is actually a macro expanding to `\delimiter "444A471` and needs to be protected from expansion to avoid tripping up the math parser.

So you need

```
\def\a{{%
"\llparenthesis"%
,"\noexpand\llbracket"%
,"\llparenthesis"%
}}
```